# Show that $f_n=\cos(\pi+\frac{x}{n})$ converges uniformly, and find the uniform limit.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$,  $f_n=\cos(\pi+\frac{x}{n})$. Show the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly, and find the uniform limit.

I often struggle with proving uniform convergence, I wasn't sure if I should try to do it from first principles, or use the fact that $[0,2]$ is compact, and try to show that $f_n(x)$ is decreasing after some $n$, and then use Dini's theorem. I dont seem to be able to show $f_n$ is decreasing at each $x$ without pictures. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a Taylor series and bounding the error?

Comment: You can see that if $f_n$ converges pointwise to -1. Now you need to check if this pointwise convergence is in fact uniform. Or you need to check how $\sup_{x\in [0,2]} | -1 + \cos(\pi+\frac{x}{n}) |$ behaves.

Comment: Have you worked out what the limit is? I think this is quite doable from first principles.

Comment: Just use $|\cos x - \cos y | \leq |x-y|$.

Comment: Also, to show that $\{f_n\}$ is monotone (in order to use Dini's theorem), all you have to do is consider that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n$ is increasing on $[0, 2]$ (this should be easy to show), and therefore, as $f_{n+1}(x) = f_n\left(\frac{nx}{n+1}\right)$ and $\frac{nx}{n+1} < x$, $f_{n+1}(x)\leq f_n(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that if a uniform limit exists, it must coincide with the pointwise limit.  At any $x$, we calculate
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos\left(\pi + \frac xn\right) = \cos \pi = -1
$$
Now, we wish to show that the convergence is uniform.  That is, we wish to find a uniform upper bound for the difference $|\cos(\pi) - \cos(\pi + x/n)|$.  A handy trick here is to use the mean value theorem on the function $x \mapsto \cos(\pi + x/n)$: for all $x \in [0,2]$, there exists a $c \in (0,x)$ such that
$$
(\cos(\pi) - \cos(\pi + x/n)) = \left(\left.\frac d{dx} \cos(\pi + x/n)\right|_{x=c} \right) \cdot x
$$
perhaps you could take it from there.

Comment: The last part of your method (so the OP is clear) is exactly what @PhoemueX suggested in slightly different terms.

Comment: You don't need MVT. The values of $\cos(\pi +x/n)$ lie between $-1$ and $-\cos(2/n)$. As $n\to \infty$, $-\cos2/n\to-1$. All you need is the continuity of $\cos$ at $\pi$, no differentiability is needed.

Comment: Sure, but this trick is nice because it works for other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, everything is said in the comments, but let's emphasize the concept, because it seems to be difficult for many people: usually, it's simple to see the pointwise limit $f(x)$ of a function sequence $f_n(x)$, in this case, that's just the constant $\cos\pi=-1.$ The "uniform" now just means to find an estimate for the difference $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ valid for *all* $x\in[0,2]$, i.e. it does not depend on $x$ (and has to converge to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty,$ naturally). In this case, you can use $$\left|\cos(\pi+\frac{x}{n}-\cos\pi\right|\le\frac{x}{n}\le\frac{2}{n},$$ because the derivative of $\cos$ is $\le1$ everywhere.
It's the latter estimate, $\frac{2}{n}$ independent of $x$, that turns the trick, and that's possible only because the interval is finite. On the whole real axis, there is convergence in this case as well, but no *uniform* convergence.